# How to add elements in existing array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that shows the amount of service worked minutes for each year.
But for some years, there are no service worked minutes recorded.
In these cases, I need to add "0 min".

Input:

```
const processMinutes = [
  '1990',    '180min',  '1991',
  '135 min', '1992',    '126 min',
  '1993',    '1994',    '182 min',
  '1995',    '1996',    '118 min',
  '1997',    '1998',    '136min',
  '199',     '144 min', '2000'
]
```

Output:

```
[
  '1990',    '180min',  '1991',
  '135 min', '1992',    '126 min',
  '1993',    '0 min',   '1994',
  '182 min', '1995',    '0 min',
  '1996',    '118 min', '1997',
  '0 min',   '1998',    '136min',
  '199',     '144 min', '2000',
  '0 min'
]
```

I have attempted to achieve a result, but have been unsuccessful each time I have tried.
In my opinion, I should utilize the splice array method.

```
const processMinutes = [
  '1990',    '180min',  '1991',
  '135 min', '1992',    '126 min',
  '1993',    '1994',    '182 min',
  '1995',    '1996',    '118 min',
  '1997',    '1998',    '136min',
  '199',     '144 min', '2000'
]

processMinutes.splice(7, 0, "0 min");
processMinutes.splice(11, 0, "0 min");
processMinutes.splice(15, 0, "0 min");
processMinutes.splice(21, 0, "0 min");

console.log(processMinutes)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]  (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: btw, why do you have strings for years and why not take nested array as pairs or objects with year an time properties?

Comment: *"In my opinion, I should utilize the splice array method."* If you want to modify the existing array (as you've said), yes. Please show us the attempts you said you've made.

Comment: (And as Nina suggested, this really should be an array of objects, either ones with semantically-named properties like `year` and `minutes` or at least nested arrays.)

Comment: I need a solution, not criticism.

Comment: I am giving Upvoting cause he tried to solve problem.

Comment: No one is crticizing you! Our goal is to make StackOverflow useful and clean for everyone. your question is unclear using your input and output showcase. it would be helpful if you re-frame your question so we can help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate and look ahead to the next item and add one zero time, it no time.

```js
const processMinutes = [
  '1990',    '180min',  '1991',
  '135 min', '1992',    '126 min',
  '1993',    '1994',    '182 min',
  '1995',    '1996',    '118 min',
  '1997',    '1998',    '136min',
  '199',     '144 min', '2000'
];

for (let i = 0; i < processMinutes.length; i += 2) {
    if (!processMinutes[i + 1]?.endsWith('min'))
        processMinutes.splice(i + 1, 0, '0 min');
}

console.log(...processMinutes);
```

Answer (score 1):

After you push every year into the result, check if the next item that will be pushed will end with 'min'. If not, push '0 min' before continuing to the next item in the source array.

```js
const processMinutes = ['1990','180min','1991','135 min','1992','126 min','1993','1994','182 min','1995','1996','118 min','1997','1998','136min','199','144 min','2000']

console.log(processMinutes.reduce((a,c,i,r)=>(a.push(c),
  a.length%2===1&&!(r[i+1]??'').endsWith('min')&&a.push('0 min'),a),[]))
```